why does putting a null char in string give error in c
im trying to run this code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#if defined(_WIN32)
#define SEPERATOR '\\'
#elif defined(__unix__) || defined(__linux__)
#define SEPERATOR '/'
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *path = "c/c/c/c/c";
    char *end = strrchr(path, SEPERATOR);
    *end = '\0';
    // printf("%s",end);
    printf("%s",path);
    // printf("%c",SEPERATOR);
}

i want to remove the last c from the string. why does this program give segmentation fault. i know it's something to do with memory management. but please shed some light on this.

strrchr will return a null pointer if it cannot find the character, which in your code will happen for windows.

You can't write to string literals, that's why. Change char *path to char path[]. See the linked duplicate FAQ for details.

yes but the path variable is a placeholder which will change as per the os but please help with the segmentation fault

@neo Writing to a null pointer will cause a segmentation fault. But it's mainly what Lundin wrote

@neo, writing to a string literal is undefined behavior (UB).  It might "work", might not.  It is UB.

what if i use char* and then allocate memory to it and then try to this operation would it work? @Lundin
